# Facing errors while deploying my code on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Code showing these errors when used `git push heroku main`. And how to resolve these conflicting dependencies

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        rebuilt dependencies successfully
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: react-top-loading-bar@2.1.0
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
remote:        npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   5 more (react-dom, react-infinite-scroll-component, ...)
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-top-loading-bar@2.1.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react-top-loading-bar
remote:        npm ERR!   react-top-loading-bar@"^2.1.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-top-loading-bar@2.1.0
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/react-top-loading-bar
remote:        npm ERR!     react-top-loading-bar@"^2.1.0" from the root project
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have react buildpack defined in your heroku project settings?

Comment: No what is that

Comment: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=react
how to set buildpack on heroku - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Yeah added that but still getting the same error

Comment: have you maybe by mistake commited your `node_modules`?

Comment: yeah I actually had done that, Thanks for the help its working now

Comment: Close the question